# Execute local application via PHP from server

Tags: php

My company has an internal Linux server running PHP with an application that displays client specific information, such as SSH connection info, etc. Is there a way to have the server invoke a command on a local machine via PHP? For example, the server displays a link with SSH connection information, such as c:\putty.exe -ssh someone@192.168.1.100 -pw MyPassword`. The user - on a windows machine - clicks the link and Putty fires up with all the connection information.

I believe Flash's [fscommand](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary372.html) has the capabilities I'm looking for, although I would much prefer to use PHP, if at all possible.

Comment: woah....would we really want that?  I know I don't want some server using PHP to start software on my PC.

Comment: I know this goes against every security rule in the book, but this is for internal use only, and as such I believe would be "acceptable." However, as answered below, the proper - and possibly only viable - would be to use other technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side technology and as such does not have any control over the client. You'll have to use a client side tech like flash or if it's IE only, ActiveX

Comment: Thank you, I thought this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to things like this is mount your resource on server machine. To do that you have to have a server that will be visible for server and able to host your files.